# How to pass environment variables to docker container app user

Tags: docker

Using Docker Compose, how do you pass environment variables to the app user shell such that the environment variables are always loaded when that user runs a command?

For example, I have tried via Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby26

ENV FOO=bar

RUN dpkg --clear-avail
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get -qq update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get -qq install -f
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get -qq install -y build-essential apt apt-utils \
                           software-properties-common wget inetutils-ping \
                           sudo netcat

COPY --chown=app:app . .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh is:

```sh
_user="$(id -u -n)"
echo "User name : $_user"

su - app -c 'echo "**************** root printenv:"'
printenv
su - app -c 'echo "**************** app printenv:"'
su - app -c 'printenv'
```

<s>The `build`/`run` output includes a number of existing/pre-set variables -- but not `FOO`.</s> When I don't use sudo, I can see the variable in the `printenv` run as root. However, the variable is not available to app user.

What is the best way to make FOO available to user `app`? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` in Docker at all, but one of its features is cleaning the environment; the linked question describes the `sudo -E` option.  I might focus on including your application in the Dockerfile over trying to make an interactive debugging shell work well.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I changed out sudo for su in the script, and I can see FOO=bar in the *root* user printenv. What is the preferred way of getting that to app user?

Comment: You shouldn't need `su` in Docker at all.  Just set your image's `USER`, or the `docker run -u` option, to the user you need.

Comment: I take your point, But the script is only to show the symptom of the problem: When I set environment variables in compose or env_file, they are only available to root. Hence my question.

Comment: Try `docker run -u app --entrypoint /bin/env your-image`.  You should see the environment variables you set in the image, and you're running as the application user.